# Hide Character When It Leaves Room

Tags: modifiers, objects, shaders, compositing-nodes

Wondering how I could prevent a character from being rendered on the other side of a wall as they leave an room.  Viewing from above the room and character goes out a door and the character is rendered on the other side of the room.  Want the character to not render/show up on the other side of the door. Still want to see the character thru the door.  So one small area, as viewed from above, I don't want to change.

Options I was looking at:
Boolean Modifier - Object above door use with Boolean modifier.  The character has a lot of materials/parts...  Assuming I would have to apply the boolean modifier to all the parts? Did this for single object/mesh works good.  (assuming same issue with lattice modifier option i saw)

Mask - Was trying to wrap my mind around doing a holdout (mask) but i can't figure out what to do to only have that one spot not show the character but still show the character show everywhere else. Also how to put it all together afterwards (have not done layers or this before just watched a few yt videos that made me think maybe this would work)

Other - Some other compositing option

Anyways any help would be appreciated.

Solution I ended up using:
Duplicate character. Joined everything added the boolean. Brought the “stunt double” in when it was time to head off into the next room.

Comment: You should be able to animate its visibility in the render.  At frame 1 hover over its render visibility (camera icon) in the outliner), right click and select 'insert keyframe'.  Go to the frame you want it to disappear, toggle the visibility, right click and select 'insert keyframe'.  It'll be included in the render during those frames but invisible otherwise.  You can do this toggle again if you want the character to become visible again.

Comment: it could be possible through the Compositor, maybe show a picture of your character and scene